# How to calculate all the points defining two crossing circles in Python?

Tags: python, geometry

I want to calculate the points defining two crossing circles in Python. See the plot below of the points I want to calculate.

[image]

I have the following algorithm to calculate the point defining one circle :

```
def get_circle_points(x_center, y_center, radius, n=20):
    xpoints = []
    ypoints = []
    for i in range(0, n+1):
        x = math.cos(2*math.pi/n*i) * radius + x_center
        y =  math.sin(2*math.pi/n*i) * radius + y_center
        xpoints.append(x)
        ypoints.append(y)
    return xpoints, ypoints
```

One important limitation is that I can't import `numpy`, only pure Python answer are ok.

Comment: As an aside: You can never calculate _all_ of those points. There are an infinite number of them.

Comment: It looks like you just want the points that are on the boundary of one circle and not inside the other circle.

Comment: Sorry Chris maybe I wasn't clear I want to discretize the shape and calculate points on it. One of the parameter would be the density of those points `n` (see the Python script).

Comment: Yes BrenBarn and also a way to get those points in the correct order so I can draw a Polygon with the list of points.

Comment: So checking for points inside the other circle works perfectly to get the **set** of points defining the wanted shape. But I need to get the **list** of points in the correct order so I can draw a polygon from this list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple approach (with some excessive calculations):

Get start angle as

```
sa = atan2(yc2-yc1, xc2-xc1)
```

Generate the first circle points in angle range `sa..sa + 2*Pi`

Check - if point (px,py) is outside the second circle, add it to result list `(px-cx2)^2+(py-cy2)^2 > r2^2`

Generate the second circle points in angle range `sa - Pi..sa + Pi`

Check - if point (px,py) is outside the first circle, add it to result list `(px-cx1)^2+(py-cy1)^2 > r1^2`

More effective approach - calculate intersection points angles and scan only needed angle ranges.